# How to make a post call with Django where your models are many to many?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand how I should be structuring my post call when I want to do a many to many relationship.

```
class School(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, blank=True)
    teachersAtSchool = models.ManyToManyField('Teacher',  blank=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    account           = models.ForeignKey(Account, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    schoolsTeachingAt = models.ManyToManyField('School', blank=True)
```

I send in the following JSON:

```
{
"name": "school Name",
"teachersAtSchool": 0
}
```

and get the following result:

```
  {
  "id": 13,
  "name": "school Name",
  "teachersAtSchool": []
  }
```

Edit: Showing serialize

```
class SchoolModelSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta():
        model = models.School
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

class TeacherModelSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta():
        model = models.Teacher
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

I have checked there are indeed teachers in the database that I can get with my GET call. I even tried with different id's but I get the same result. Its possible this is something super simple I just don't understand. Please help me.

Regards

Comment: I think the issue might be in your serializers. Can you provide the serializer code to be sure? I suspect you didn't specify nested serialization. Check out this resource: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: Try posting this: `{ "name": "school Name", "teachersAtSchool": [1]}` (I doubt you have a `Teacher` with an `id` of `0`.

Comment: I don't think you need depth=1. As ModelSerializers do primary keys by default.

Comment: @RossRogers idea seems good, but I think you need to check what your ModelSerializer class actually generates using [inspecting a model serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer). And of course to repeat: I don't think depth is needed.

Comment: I would also suggest rather doing a joining table for your Many-to-Many relationship. ie. a `class SchoolTeacher(models.Model)` to join the School and Teacher

Comment: Also try and play with the serializer by itself because the json input it expects is the same as the json output it creates. So if you have a valid school with teachers, print what the serializer would output. That should give you valid input for the serializer.

Comment: To pass values to the array as MxM field you need to rewrite the `create(self, validated_data)` method. It is the best way. Nevertheless, if you will need to create many nested GET and POST endpoints I would recommend you to use graphql.

Answer (score 1):

@simple_code said: "I don't think you need depth=1. As ModelSerializers do primary keys by default. – simple_code"

This resulted in it defaulting back to id which was the solution.

I found this answer out by following their suggestion "Also try and play with the serializer by itself because the json input it expects is the same as the json output it creates. So if you have a valid school with teachers, print what the serializer would output. That should give you valid input for the serializer. - simple_code" and noticing the json I received back was the whole serialized class.

Thank you everyone for you help and suggestions. I hope this post helps anyone.